# Default dispatcher for a custom scope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I have a class (singleton) that regularly refreshes cache of Cms values, this is inside a [Ktor](https://ktor.io/) API

My implementation looks something like this:

```
class CmsProviderImpl {
  private val scope = CoroutineScope(Job())

  init {
      // Launch a new coroutine for refresh cache items
      scope.launch {
          while (isActive) {
              delay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(900))
              refreshCacheCmsItems()
          } 
      }
  }
}
```

I know Ktor uses Dispatcher.IO by default in its Scopes, but what about this case?
Should I specify the Dispatcher explicitly or CoroutineScope is smart enough to know to use Dispatcher.IO as well?

Looking for the best approach to run these types of tasks in background.

Comment: "I know Ktor uses Dispatcher.IO by default" - are you sure about this? I don't say this is not true, but generally the default dispatcher in Kotlin is... well, `Dispatchers.Default`. We should avoid using `IO` if not doing a blocking I/O. Answering your question: no, no one can force your own scope to use a different dispatcher than you chose. Your scope uses `Dispatchers.Default` as this is default.

Comment: I don't think I've seen a more obscure way to represent 15 minutes before. What's the advantage over just passing 900_000? But more importantly, `TimeUnit` has a `MINUTES` constant as well.

Comment: @Jorn you made my day XD I think it should be noted that we can also use Kotlin durations: `delay(15.minutes)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a `CoroutineScope` and are explicitly using it. No, of course there's no magic here that'll change it to `Dispatchers.IO`. However, you can change that manually by passing `Dispatchers.IO` to `CoroutineScope()` instead of a plain new `Job`.

Comment: Got it. I had a feeling this was the case, but reading that scopes being inherited from the parent did confuse me a bit since Ktor endpoints are suspend functions that already provide a scope.